# .animate() left position decrease changing all elements in container to same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a really basic sliding carousel that users can navigate left or right. The script I'm using is automatically assigning an absolute left position to each item in the wrapper div and it's *almost* behaving as expected. However, when I click on my left or right navigation buttons, instead of decreasing/increasing the the current value for left positioning on each item, it's changing them all to the same value (which seems to be determined by the first item in the group).

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

This is the sample of my button click action:

```
$('.leftarrow').on('click', function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({ left: '-=200' }, 1000);    
  });
});
```

---

*Edited to add snippet of all code*

```js
  var $item = $('.singleItem');

  var curX = 0;
  var move = 0;

  $item.each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', curX);

    curX += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    move = $(this).outerWidth();
  });

  $leftArrow = $('.leftarrow');
  $rightArrow = $('.rightarrow');

  $leftArrow.on('click', function() {
    $item.each(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        left: '-=255'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });

  $rightArrow.on('click', function() {
    $item.each(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        left: '+=255'
      }, 1000);
    });

  });
```

```css
.scrolling_container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.scrolling_container .scrolling_inner {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.singleItem {
  background: #dbdae0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 255px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrolling_container">
  <div class="rightarrow">
    <h1>&raquo;</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="leftarrow">
    <h1>&laquo;</h1>
  </div>

  <ul class="scrolling_inner">
    <li class="singleItem">CONTENT</li>
    <li class="singleItem">CONTENT</li>
    <li class="singleItem">CONTENT</li>
    <li class="singleItem">CONTENT</li>
    <li class="singleItem">CONTENT</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: You are applying the exact same property to each item in an each loop - so tall ".items" are all going to move, in a loop, left: -200 for 1 second each everytime you click that arrow. If each start point is the same, the end point will be the same. What you want to do is add a counter that applies the animate based on which child is actually active and needs to slide into view. Each click the counter adds one until it equals the number of slides - then resets to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working ok, I'd guess something else in your code is messing with it. Can you provide a snippet of the code surrounding that?

```js
$('.leftarrow').on('click', function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({ left: '-=200' }, 1000);    
  });
});
```

```css
.item { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="leftarrow">left</button>

<div class="item" style="top: 110px; left: 20px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 120px; left: 200px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 30px; left: 80px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 40px; left: 230px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 50px; left: 120px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 60px; left: 0px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 70px; left: 190px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 80px; left: 310px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 90px; left: 40px;">ITEM</div>
<div class="item" style="top: 100px; left: 60px;">ITEM</div>
```

Comment: I just edited my question to include the HTML/CSS/JS that I'm using - and you're right, it _is_ working! So now I need to find the piece that's colliding. This is the page that I'm testing: https://feelthevive.com/collections/v2-our-raving-fans-are-feelin-the-vive

The only thing that I can think of is that this is a Shopify site built with liquid - but why would that change anything. So frustrating.